# Tiny MCE - Just boil me is failing to upload image

Tags: php, html, upload, tinymce, justboil.me

when I try to upload an image, the upload seems to start but not finish.its giving me following message
[image]

I tried waiting for 15 minutes for a few kb image file but it doesn't work at all.

i configured this plug in as per their instruction given here : **[Just Boil Me](http://justboil.me/)** and i can confirm that i didn't miss anything, i changed the config file and my html for TINYMCE 3.X as per their suggestion. I also followed the just boil me issues mentioned here : **[GITHUB](https://github.com/vikdiesel/justboil.me/issues)** but the solutions did not help me.

Could you please be kind to look into this and let me know what's going wrong, where should i look and whats the solution ?

**UPDATE :**

There is one hint i got from inspect element -> network tab. Ater clicking on the image icon two red rows are appearing in network tab.  the screenshot is attached below
[image]

Comment: what error do you get on console tab at developer tools ?

Comment: @MArgusChopinGyver no error... i also checked console & network. couldn't find any hint or help

Comment: if a solution is not known a hint/any idea will also be great helpful.. i dont know how much sense this comment is making lol

Comment: no error from server log too

Comment: I think, the best solution for now, upgrade your tinymce to version 4.x.x. Because I'm using the same plugin on 4.3.10 and it works well

Comment: @MArgusChopinGyver  tell me one thing please... did you require to change the **action code in the dialog-v4.htm** or something to the controller

Comment: nope, nothing change except the config.php (change the target directory for uploaded photo)

Comment: Open browser console, tab called "Network". And try again. You will see some POST request I think. And I think there should be some error message there. Tell us what you see there.

Comment: @BogdanBurim ... I just uploaded the screenshot and yes there are two rows appeared in red after i clicked on the image upload icon.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of struggle i found the remedy of this issue. Two html files of just boil me need to be corrected to resolve the issue. the files are **`dialog-v4.htm`** and **`dialog.htm`**. these two files can be found in root folder of just boil me extract.

There is a html form used in both files mentioned above. you will need to change the value of **`action`** for those two forms.

1. Change ***form action*** from `"ci/index.php/upload/{#jbimages_dlg.lang_id}"` to `"ci/?upload/{#jbimages_dlg.lang_id}"` in **dialog.htm**
2. Change ***form action*** from `"ci/index.php?upload/english"` to `"ci/?upload/english"` in **dialog-v4.htm**

and your issue is resolved now.